# How do I run a command line command in a Python script?

Tags: python

I'm using 2 separate scripts, `Scale1.py` and `Scale2.py`. To run them I enter `sudo python Scale1.py` or `sudo python Scale2.py` from the terminal command line. I would like to have a line in the `Scale2.py` script in which if I press a button, the program breaks and runs `Scale1.py`. Something like this, which doesn't work.

```py
if GPIO.input(23) == False:
    break(sudo python Scale1.py)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`os.system("sudo python scale1.py")`

first you will need to import the os module

`import os`

I don't have a pi with me atm to test, but this comes from the second answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Comment: This is what I tried and it worked, thanks a lot Harry! But I did have to combine both programs first. Now the os.system("sudo python Scale3.py") simply restarts at the beginning of Scale3.py program, which is fine. I think import Scale3.py will also work. I didn't try subprocess, it does look interesting and is probably something I need to learn.

Comment: `os.system()` has been depricated in favor of `subprocess`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4256153/4212158

Answer (score 12):

In general, use the ***subprocess*** module

```
subprocess.call(["sudo","python","scale1.py"])
```

for command line calls.

An example processing the result of a subprocess call;

```
 result = subprocess.check_output(['sudo','service','mpd','restart'])
```

**Subprocess** replaces several older modules and functions, like *os.system* and *os.spawn*. It does a good job in sanitizing arguments, so it protects you from *shell injection*.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Of course to run a second python script there is no need for CLI call, you can import those.

Comment: I'm trying to learn how to issue commands from within a Python script (see [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/80271/35753) and [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/80219/35753)) and having some problems. I wonder if `subprocess` might be better in my case as well.

Answer (score 6):

You can use sudo as harry sib suggested, but you would have to add the user running the first script to the [sudoers file](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html).

The best way to run a python script from another python script is to import it. You should have the logic of your script in a method in the second script:

```
# Scale2.py
def run():
    do_first()
    do_second()
    [...]

# Run it only if called from the command line
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

```
# Scale1.py
import Scale2

if (GPIO.input(23) == False):
    Scale2.run()
```

Comment: +1, Since python is capable of this, it will be the `cleanest` answer.

Comment: +1, this is the correct way to do what the OP wants and should probably be the accepted answer.